# Checking textboxes if empty to control visibility of subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form with textboxes for adding new Event to the database. Some of the textboxes are mandatory while the rest not. Within this also is a subform for adding details of participants.

I don't want the subform to be visible if one or more of the mandatory fields have nothing. I have tried with this but the subform stays invisible regardless whether or not there is data in the mandatory fields:

```
Dim ctl As Control   
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
      If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
           If Not (IsNull(ctl.Value) Or ctl.Value = "") Then
              Me.subfrmParticipants.Visible = False
           Else
              Me.subfrmParticipants.Visible = True
           End If
      End If
Next ctl
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a double negative instead of just checking for NULL value in your text box.

Change this

`If Not (IsNull(ctl.Value) Or ctl.Value = "") Then`

To This:

`If (IsNull(ctl.Value) Or ctl.Value = "") Then`

Then if the text box is assigned a database NULL value or is empty,
then the hide subform command will kick in